# Adding a realtime listener inside Flutter test

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, listener

I am writing test for a Flutter App but I need to listen to a Firestore Collection to tell the app which test to run. And for that I need to implement a listener. However, the test stops even before reaching to the listener and no test case executes.

Here's my code for main

```
  void main async{
 group('TEST COORDINATOR', () {
    IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    print('run WorkerTestCoordinator');
    setupLocator();
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    Firebase.initializeApp().then((value) => ApplicationTestCoordinator());
  });
}
```

And here's code for ApplicationTestCoordinator()

```
class ApplicationTestCoordinator {
  ApplicationTestCoordinator() {
    print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 1");
    try {
      //listen for new tests
      Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshots;
      print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 2");
      snapshots = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('_integration_tests')
          .snapshots();
      print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 3");
      snapshots.listen((event) async {
        List<DocumentChange> changedDocs = event.docChanges;
        for (int index = 0; index < changedDocs.length; index++) {
          String documentID = changedDocs[index].doc.id;
          Map documentData = changedDocs[index].doc.data();
          if (changedDocs[index].type == DocumentChangeType.added) {
            print("ApplicationTestCoordinator >> document added:" + documentID);
           testWidgets("INTEGRATION TESTS", (tester) async {
                tester.printToConsole("hello");
                //run worker
                app.main();
                await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 6));

                //the tests
                await login.login(tester);
              });
          }
        }
      });
      print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 4");

      //});
    } catch (e, stack) {
      //TODO add error handling and reporting
      print("ERRORRRRR>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
      print(e.toString());
      print(stack);
    }
  }
}
```

As soon as it reaches to `snapshots.listen` the test stops and it won't go inside the listener.

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error? Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65087630/4224925) should be working.

Comment: @xBurnsed No exception, the test just exists.

Comment: Only for testing purposes to discard things.. but what if you tried it whitout the async function? Same outcome?

Comment: @xBurnsed Yes, it doesn't go inside listener function

Comment: Strange! I have personally tested it with Cloud Firestore version 7.22.1 on my index.html and it works for me! Could you check your chrome console to see if any errors are raised?

Comment: @xBurnsed It works on web. It doesn't work on mobile

Comment: I wonder if this has something to do with the fact you are doing it inside a test. What if you tried doing something similar outside your test code? Does it work for you? If this is the case, this probably has something to do with the fact that your test is not detecting your Firestore App and you would have to do something to configure it.

Comment: @xBurnsed Yes, it works outside the test. And it also works if I use get() instead of snapshot() in the test

Comment: It is possible that inside a test you have to Mock your Firestore data. For more info and an example, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268590/how-to-unit-test-methods-using-firebase-cloud-firestore) and read the comments under the OPs post, and also [this](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_architecture_samples/blob/master/firebase_flutter_repository/test/firebase_flutter_repository_test.dart).